# Use UISearchBar to search NSDates (which are strings using NSDateFormatter) in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, core-data, nspredicate

I have a table view which is currently searching through string attributes of a Core Data database perfectly. It however is not searching through dates.

My dates are NSDates, but displayed to the user as strings with NSDateFormatter.

I'm using Core Data.

My current predicate in the fetchresultscontroller is like this:

```
if ([self.timelineSearchBar.text length] > 0) {
    NSPredicate *predName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY whoBy.name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.timelineSearchBar.text];
    NSPredicate *predOccasion = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY occasion.title CONTAINS[c] %@", self.timelineSearchBar.text];
    NSPredicate *predDate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY dates.dateOfEvent CONTAINS[c] %@", self.timelineSearchBar.text];


NSPredicate *compPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predName, predOccasion, predDate]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:compPredicate];
```

With that, I can search for "names" and "occasion titles". However, I cannot search for dates.

The dates are formatted as:

```
-(NSString *)sectionDateFormatter
{
    // this can be fancier if you need a custom format or particular timezone:
    return [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:self.dates.dateOfEvent
                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle
                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
}
```

However when I search for any date, it's not displaying at all. Is there anyway I can get dates searching here as well (without having to create another fetchedResultsController, etc)?

Thanks and any thoughts are welcome!

**EDIT: Including how I save dates**

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [cal
                                components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
NSDate *selectedDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSPredicate will allow search on dates using typical comparison operators.  Remember, though, that users have a much fuzzier understanding of dates than the device, so the search should almost always include inequalities...

```
NSDate *startDate = // date from the user's input, minus a little, like to the start of the specified day
NSDate *endDate = // date from the user's input, plus a little, like to the end of the specified day

NSPredicate *dateRangePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateOfEvent >= %@) AND (dateOfEvent <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
NSPredicate *compPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate // as you have it
```

Comment: please be sure to check my predicate string, since i don't know how your model is structured.

Comment: Thanks very much - that's massively appreciated! My question is.. (perhaps even a different question here) is.. how would I get the startDate and endDate? I've edited my question to include how I'm saving the dates to Core Data (no times at all) - how would I go about generating startDate? Sorry, a fair newbie here!

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I'm doing the fetchRequest in another view controller when the core data information has already been saved.. should I therefore create additional attributes in my "Dates" Entity to hold the start and end date, which I can then reference in the NSFetchedResultsController, or is that over complicating it?

Comment: In general, think of NSDates as the only way to represent dates.  NSString is only for the very last step, to present a date to a human.  In other words, as soon as the user input is complete, turn it into a date.  Store only NSDates in CoreData and do all search computation with NSDates.  Once a record is retrieved, you can use a date formatter to create a string for user.

Comment: Thanks @danh and absolutely, after messing around with dates for a long time, I've learnt to store dates in Core Data as NSDates and just display it to users in a friendly manner. I understand your answer now - I'm just not sure if I should create two new attributes in the Dates Entity called startDate and endDate of type NSDate - save those in the save method and then in the separate table view, reference those objects? I understand the concept - just want to make sure I understand where to place everything

Comment: I think it depends on the semantics.  If the thing that entity represents is like a calendar entry (that has a beginning and end) then maybe two dates (or a start and duration) makes sense.  If it's more like an instant in time, then one date.  If you do have two dates, then that complicates the search logic a little, since you might be looking for overlapping ranges, i.e. you'll be asking if either the start or end date in the search falls in between the start-end date of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components;

    // Today starts today - remove any time components
    components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:date];
    _todayStartDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    // Tomorrow starts tomorrow so add one day
    [components setMonth:0];
    [components setDay:1]; //reset the other components
    [components setYear:0]; //reset the other components
    _tomorrowsStartDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:_todayStartDate options:0];

    NSPredicate *dateRangePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateOfEvent >= %@) AND (dateOfEvent < %@)", _todayStartDate, _tomorrowsStartDate];
```

Alternately make sure you store remove all time components from your NSDate before you store it in Core Data which will allow you to do a search with "dateOfEvent==%@", _todayStartDate

```
        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *components = [cal
                  components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
        NSDate *selectedDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

        // Remove any time components
        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate: selectedDate];
        NSDate *dateToStore = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

EDIT:

I just realised the search is using text typed into a searchBar so the above approach will not work because we need to match a string.  It may not be possible to convert what the user entered in the searchBar into a NSDate.  I solved this problem by creating a NSManagedObject subclass and creating a methods on the subclass to convert the date to a string.  Using this approach I set a transient attribute called 'found' on the objects and then use this attribute to filter the list that gets displayed - actually because of the hierarchical structure I just highlight the elements in the structure that contain nodes with matches.

```
- (NSString*)stringFromDate:(NSDate*)date {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Then on the same subclass a method to check whether the attribute value contains a search string

```
    - (BOOL)checkAttribute:(NSString*)value searchString:(NSString*)searchString
    {
        if (searchString == nil || value == nil) return NO;

        NSRange range = [value rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
        else {
            return YES;
        }
}
```

And then finally a bunch of search methods that will also search any child nodes

```
- (BOOL)containsSearchString:(NSString*)string
{
    // Start of a search so reset found.
    self.found = NO;

    _lastSearchString = string;
    if ([self containsString:string])
        self.found = YES;

    if ([self childContainsString:string])
        self.found = YES;

    return self.found;

}
-(BOOL)containsString:(NSString*)searchString
{
    if ([self checkAttribute:self.displayName searchString:searchString])
        return YES;
    if ([self checkAttribute:self.reminderPeriod searchString:searchString])
        return YES;
    if ([self checkAttribute:[self stringFromDate:self.reminderDate] searchString:searchString])
        return YES;
    if ([self checkAttribute:self.details.string searchString:searchString])
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
- (BOOL)childContainsString:(NSString*)searchString {

    for (OSTreeNode *child in self.children) {

        if ([child containsSearchString:searchString])
            self.found = YES;

    }

    return self.found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan - That's very helpful! Just a quick question - do I put that in the NSFetchedResultsController method of the table view.. and fromDate:date - can date here be from Core Data (in my case, dateOfEvent) ,or do I do this in the save method before I save to Core Data, and therefore create a todayStartDate and tomorrowStartDate NSDate Attribute in my Date Entity? I hope this makes sense.. so to reiterate.. my questions are, where should this code go, and should todayStartDate and tomorrowStartDate be NSDate attributes in my "Dates" entity? Thanks again!

Comment: Ummm... OK sorry you are trying to search the dates in the database using a string entered into the searchBar!  This is not going to work because fromDate:??  parameter must be a date so whatever has been entered into the searchBar would have to be converted to a NSDate first - that might be difficult if its just a string!

Comment: Thanks Duncan - sorry it's confusing, but that makes sense.. a searchBar would never be able to search a Date! Wow.. I got to figure this one out proper! Thanks again Dunacan

Comment: You could solve this by storing the date as a string in Core Data and then your original approach using 'CONTAINS [cd] %@' would work. However you would be stuck with whatever date format you used to store the stringDate.  For example '01/01/2013'  or '1 Jan 2013' or '01-01-2013' etc...  Also you need to convert for timezone differences.

Comment: Of course you could create a string containing all possible date formats in it '01-01-2013 1 January 2013 01/01/2013 1 Jan 2013' - that would work too !